# Default Pathway for Ant

Tags: java, android, ant, unreal-engine4, gear-vr

I'm messing around in Unreal engine trying to play with Gear VR so I was following the instructions on Oculus' website ( 
 https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/unreal/latest/concepts/unreal-gsg-mobile/  ) and I'm having trouble with finding the pathway to ANT in Android. When I installed the Android SDK through Codeworks like it mentioned in the documentation and it went well. Anyways later in the documentation, it says that if you installed the SDK through Codeworks that the fields where the Android SDK is will already be filled in which I find weird because the fields were not filled in. Anyways I'm just looking for the default pathway to ANT. I also already tried C:\Users[Username]\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\proguard\ant When I tried to build the project in Unity it says it couldn't find ant.bat  .